# JQPlot - Uncaught exception: No plot target specified

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqplot

I'm trying to use jqplot with mvc4.
'im trying to get data for plot in the controller like the following:

Controller.cs

```
        public ActionResult DrawChart(FormCollection fc)
        {
            if (fc["start"] != null && (fc["end"] != null))
            {
                string start = fc.GetValue("start").AttemptedValue;
                string end = fc.GetValue("end").AttemptedValue;
                string connstring = "Data Source=DB.world;User ID=USER;Password=mypass;";
                using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstring))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    string sql = "select to_char(dpr_ts, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), dpr_close from dpr@price where dpr_qot_id=2029543939 and dpr_ts>='" + start + "' and  dpr_ts<='" + end + "'";
                        //"select dpr_close, dpr_ts from dpr@price where dpr_qot_id=2029543939";// and dpr_ts>='01.08.2012' and  dpr_ts<='15.11.2012'";
                    using (OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand(sql, conn))
                    {
                        using (OracleDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader())
                        {


                            var arr1 = new object[1];
                            var arr2 = new object[rdr.RowSize];
                            var ctr = 0;

                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {

                                arr2[ctr++] = new object[] {  rdr.GetOracleString(0).Value, rdr.GetOracleDecimal(1).Value,};
                                arr1[0] = arr2;

                            }
                            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(arr1);
                            //Json(arr1);
                                ViewBag.ChartData = json;
                            Console.WriteLine(ViewBag.ChartData);
                        }
                    }

                    conn.Dispose();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Here some code of Index.cshtml

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


        var chartData = $.parseJSON("@ViewBag.ChartData");
        var chartData = eval("@ViewBag.ChartData");
        var line1 = eval("@ViewBag.ChartData");
        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', line1, {
            title: 'Default Date Axis',
            axes: { xaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer } },
            series: [{ lineWidth: 4, markerOptions: { style: 'square' } }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I debug controller I'm getting this sample output for `var json`:

`[[[\"03.09.2012\",3.1790],[\"04.09.2012\",3.16],[\"05.09.2012\",3.17],[\"06.09.2012\",3.25],[\"07.09.2012\",3.2610],[\"10.09.2012\",3.2010],[\"11.09.2012\",3.1620],[\"12.09.2012\",3.22],[\"13.09.2012\",3.2190],[\"14.09.2012\",3.26],[\"17.09.2012\",3.2790],[\"18.09.2012\",3.2490],[\"19.09.2012\",3.2620],[\"20.09.2012\",3.2610],[\"21.09.2012\",3.2610],[\"24.09.2012\",3.2410],[\"25.09.2012\",3.25],[\"26.09.2012\",3.22],[\"27.09.2012\",3.1840],[\"28.09.2012\",3.2290],[\"01.10.2012\",3.25],[\"02.10.2012\",3.27],[\"03.10.2012\",3.2310],[\"04.10.2012\",3.2580],[\"05.10.2012\",3.32],[\"08.10.2012\",3.30],[\"09.10.2012\",3.28],[\"10.10.2012\",3.25],[\"11.10.2012\",3.2790],[\"12.10.2012\",3.2490],[\"15.10.2012\",3.24],[\"16.10.2012\",3.2750],[\"17.10.2012\",3.36],[\"18.10.2012\",3.3610],[\"19.10.2012\",3.3990],[\"22.10.2012\",3.37],[\"23.10.2012\",3.32],[\"24.10.2012\",3.3290],[\"25.10.2012\",3.3310],[\"26.10.2012\",3.3720],[\"29.10.2012\",3.3810],[\"30.10.2012\",3.3690],[\"31.10.2012\",3.4290],[\"01.11.2012\",3.45],[\"20.11.2012\",3.21],[\"21.11.2012\",3.29],[\"22.11.2012\",3.31],[\"23.11.2012\",3.35],[\"26.11.2012\",3.36],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]]`

VS Debugger doesnt stop in Index.cshtml in line `var line1 = eval("@ViewBag.ChartData");`.
While debugging Javascript with firebug I'm getting `line1`  as `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong? I'd expect, that `ViewBag.ChartData = json;` would cause, that `line1` will be filled with value from `json`.

Comment: As an aside note: _The model consists of application data and business rules, and the controller mediates input, converting it to commands for the model or view_ In your code there is not separation of concerns. Your controller has SQL Code...

Comment: I'm learnig it and I don't know how can I abstract oracle data in model.

Comment: This is a very good tutorial to learn MVC http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

Comment: I' reading a tutorial for mvc4. I'm reading about models. There is written: " You can then have the database created on the fly from your classes, which enables a very clean and rapid development workflow. " . Can I also abstract data from tables, that I already have? I don't need to abstract all columns(i.e. i need only two of 50). I need only read access and wanna use either web service or oracle. You know any sample code, so I can see how can abstract data for web-service or oracle as data source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

With that you lose the content of Viewbag..

If you want to use ViewBag, you should create a view for `DrawChart` and put:

```
return View();
```